# How can I make git ignore further modification on a file without deleting it from the repository

Tags: git

Duplicate: [How to ignore a tracked file in git without deleting it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1397199/how-to-ignore-a-tracked-file-in-git-without-deleting-it)

Background: in the repository, there was a sample code file that underwent preliminary development and was tracked by git. Now the development of this sample file is done, some of its static values might be changed by another dev who want to use it as sanity check to make sure the main work is outputting expected values. However, changing static values does not need to be tracked by git and it doesn't need to be comited to the repository, but it still shows up as being modified.

I would like git to essentially ignore this file from now without deleting it from the repo, as any devs who clone the repo still need to have access to this file.

Potential:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

but this is a command that must be ran by all devs, which is not ideal.

The duplicate question was asked 4 years ago, I wonder if some new functionality has been added that allows this.